# Use pyodbc library to connect to an Hyperfilesql

Tags: python, django, hyperfilesql

Hi everyone this is my first question on this website.

So i'm working on a Python Project at work. And i have to connect my Python/Django application to an HyperfileSQL (Windev) database to write some information on the HyperFile tables.

I've installed pyodbc library to do the job. But when i was trying to make a connection in windows Cmd, it shows me this error:

> > > pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={HyperFileSQL};SERVER=Mondev1;DATABASE=SP_MONTREAL;UI
> > >       D=admin;PWD=')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in  
> > >       pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The 
> > >       driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application reques 
> > >       ted (see SQLSetEnvAttr). (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [01S00] Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

I really don't understand why the connection failed. Anyone has any idea.

Note: Sorry about my poor english level i'm french :).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access hyperfile through odbc you need the driver odbc for hyperfilesql.
You need to buy it. Then install it and configure an odbc connection to your database. Here is the documentation : 
http://doc.pcsoft.fr/fr-FR/?3044179

Then you will be able to access with python to your database through the odbc driver for hyperfilesql.

Hope it will help.